# Making a list based on a criteria of another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have an empty list called 'label', where depending on which bucket is more appropriate, it will fill the 'label' list with 0,1,or 2.

'label' is associated to the 3 'buckets':

```
# Bucket 0: 0 -7 Days --------------------------> 0
# Bucket 1: 1 - 6 Weeks (8 - 42 Days) ----------> 1
# Bucket 2: 7+ Weeks (49+ Days) ----------------> 2
```

I have another list has a length of 23411. This list's contents consist of 0 days to 1099 days. So based on this list's contents, it should populate the 'label' list.

I have tried this `for-loop` & `if-else` statement to do what I want, however it is giving me a `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`:

```
label = []
for i in range(23411):
    if ageNew[i] <= 7:
        label[i] = 0
    elif ageNew[i] <= 42:
        label[i] = 1
    else:
        label[i] = 2
```

For example:

```
list: [0, 8, 14, 14, 45, 1056, 1]
label: [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Do you want answers with `numpy`, or not? You aren't using it. To solve your error replace `label[i] =...` with `label.append(...)`.

Comment: When `label = []` then `label[0]` is "undefined", because there is no 0th element. You probably want `label.append` or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make the assignment `label[i] = something` because it doesn't exist.
Use `.append()` instead

```
label = []
for i in range(23411):
    if ageNew[i] <= 7:
        res = 0
    elif ageNew[i] <= 42:
        res = 1
    else:
        res = 2
    label.append(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list is empty so `[i]` won't work the way you expecting because that index does not exist. What about:

```
label = []
for i in range(23411):
    val = None
    if ageNew[i] <= 7:
        val = 0
    elif ageNew[i] <= 42:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 2
    label.append(val)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
label = []
for i in lists:
    if i <= 7:
        label.append(0)
    elif i >= 8 and i <= 42:
        label.append(1)
    else:
        label.append(2)
#output
[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0]
```

label

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` with a numpy array. For your example:

```
i = np.arange(23411)
label = np.where(i<=7, 0, np.where(i<=42, 1, 2))
```